# Plesk How to install additional modules?

Tags: node.js, npm, plesk, hummus.js

i have troubles using Node Js with Plesk. I have a Root Server (Ubuntu + Plesk Onyx) and installed Node Js. My API runs well. But now I have a new API Build, and must install new Node modules. (Hummus.js) When I want to install it through my package.json I get =

> Execution filemng has failed with exit code 1, stdout:
>   hummus@1.0.81 install /var/www/vhosts/XXX/api.XXX/node_modules/hummus
>   node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

I think the problem is failed dependencies for Hummus.

So I want to do

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

But how can I run it with plesk? I have only a "NPM Install" button but it run install package.json

Answer (score 1):

Plesk locates `npm` for its node versions under `/opt/plesk/node`. Like `/opt/plesk/node/6` or `/opt/plesk/node/7` So to install modules you should run:

```
/opt/plesk/node/7/bin/npm install -g node-gyp
```